# Update local repo and fork with main repo GITHUB

Tags: git, github

The results of "git remote -v":

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:fec-cms jcarroll$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/johnnyporkchops/fec-cms.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/johnnyporkchops/fec-cms.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/johnnyporkchops/fec-cms.git (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/johnnyporkchops/fec-cms.git (push)
```

https://github.com/johnnyporkchops/fec-cms.git is my forked repo.
I need to update my local and forked repo with changes to the main repo(the one i forked from, https://github.com/18F/fec-cms.git) before I can go forward and fix and error in my current pull request.

How would I do that? Do I need to make a branch and clone the main repo and merge? I am new to github and still grasping the concept of "upstream" and what it means.

Comment: This is in the documentation: [Configuring a remote for a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/) and [Syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/)

Comment: Don't I need to change the upstream to pin to the main repo and not my fork, Example: Johns-MacBook-Pro:fec-cms jcarroll$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/18F/fec-cms.git
fatal: remote upstream already exists.

Comment: Do: `git remote rm upstream` and `git remote add upstream https://github.com/18F/fec-cms` then `git fetch upstream`